# Webpack SASS loader with alias not compiling under Mocha

Tags: sass, webpack, mocha.js

I have a component that loads styles like this. The `css` directory is somewhere else; here it is being used as a Webpack alias.

```
import 'css/components/PromptText';
// ...
class PromptText extends React.Component {
    // ...
}
```

Here is my `webpack.config.json`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: 'dist',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
    }, {
      test: /\.json/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'json',
    }, {
      test: /\.scss/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'],
    }],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      css: 'css', // <-- Alias here
    },
    root: path.resolve(__dirname),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],
  },
};
```

---

Now, I have a test like this for Mocha:

```
import PromptText from '../../src/components/PromptText';

describe('PromptText', () => {
  it('should display words');
});
```

When Mocha imports the component, it also tries to load the CSS component. There are two problems with this:

1. The `css` directory has been aliased. Mocha needs to know where the alias points. To fix this, I have installed the `babel-plugin-webpack-alias` package, with the following `.babelrc`:

   ```
   {
     "presets": ["es2017", "react", "stage-0"],
     "env": {
       "test": {
         "plugins": [
           ["webpack-alias", {"config": "webpack.config.js"}]
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. CSS can't be imported by Mocha, so it needs to be ignored. I use the `ignore-styles` package and invoke Mocha as `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ignore-styles`.

Despite having done these two things, I get the following error when trying to run tests:

```
(cd data && make)
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ignore-styles \
         $(find test -type f -name 'test*.js')
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'css'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/waleed/Workspace/js/steno/src/components/PromptText.jsx:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at loader (/Users/waleed/Workspace/js/steno/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:146:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .jsx] (/Users/waleed/Workspace/js/steno/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:156:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/waleed/Workspace/js/steno/test/components/testPromptText.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at loader (/Users/waleed/Workspace/js/steno/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:146:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/waleed/Workspace/js/steno/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:156:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /Users/waleed/Workspace/js/steno/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:220:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/waleed/Workspace/js/steno/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:217:14)
    at Mocha.run (/Users/waleed/Workspace/js/steno/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:485:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/waleed/Workspace/js/steno/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:403:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
    at node.js:405:3
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

For some reason, the `css` alias isn't being resolved. **However, this error only happens sometimes**, unpredictably. In order to consistently recreate this error, I have to set `BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1` in the environment.

How can I get my Mocha test to correctly import and ignore the CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, I switched from the `babel-plugin-webpack-alias` to the `babel-plugin-webpack-aliases` package, and update my `.babelrc` to use it:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2017", "react", "stage-0"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        ["webpack-aliases", {"config": "webpack.config.js"}]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I also always run `mocha` with `BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1` set in the environment. (I think this is undoing the damage that `babel-plugin-webpack-alias` did; it may not be necessary on every run if that package was never used.)